# Encapsulating behavior spread across multiple event handlers

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, event-handling

I wrote a chatbot in Ruby for [turntable.fm](http://turntable.fm), a chatroom where users can listen to music together. It interacts with users in a room, who can type in specific keywords and get responses from it. It also enforces some rules. For example, if people playing music go AFK for too long, it will force them to stop playing music.

The chatbot's overall architecture is that it has a number of event handlers that respond to various changes in the chatroom's state. For example, it can respond to a user joining the room or someone posting to the room. (These handlers are provided using the Turntabler gem ([RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/turntabler), [GitHub](https://github.com/obrie/turntabler)).)

The problem I've run into is that there are pieces of code throughout the project that are logically related, but spread out throughout multiple event handlers. Is there some pattern that will let me refactor related pieces of code into the same class?

For example, one thing the chatbot does is keep track of a queue of users that want to play music when the room is full. When a spot to play music opens up, it makes sure that only the person at the front of the queue can get up.

To get this to work, I created a [`RoomQueue`](https://github.com/KevinNorth/Kevbot/blob/9435ccbaa1c725fd7f74fa1d36da2ffd27cd2014/src/queue/room_queue.rb) class that wraps an `Array` with queue management functions. Then I put the queue in a [`KevbotState`](https://github.com/KevinNorth/Kevbot/blob/9435ccbaa1c725fd7f74fa1d36da2ffd27cd2014/src/kevbot_state.rb) class, a questionable class that keeps track of objects representing the chatbot's state. The bot spins up one instance of `KevbotState` and passes it around liberally, meaning that its members smell to me like glorified global variables.

```
require_relative 'queue/room_queue.rb'

# Keeps track of the current state of the robot.
# These are basically global variables. To keep the code half-way sane,
# I put them all into the same class. For example, this means that we
# pass the state around, avoiding singleton pattern code smells by
# directly accessing the variable's values.
class KevbotState
  #...snip

  # This keeps track of the DJ queue
  attr_reader :room_queue

  #...snip

  def initialize(client)
    @room_queue = RoomQueue.new
    #...snip
  end
end
```

Then, [in the file that defines the event handlers](https://github.com/KevinNorth/Kevbot/blob/9435ccbaa1c725fd7f74fa1d36da2ffd27cd2014/src/main.rb), there are multiple places that interact directly with this `RoomQueue`. (The main thing to get from the next code snippit is that there are a lot of places that manipulate the `RoomQueue`.)

```
require 'turntabler'
require_relative "kevbot_state.rb"

#...snip    

# Set up a connection to the room and hooks to the event handlers    
Turntabler.run do
  client = Turntabler::Client.new(ENV['EMAIL'], ENV['PASSWORD'],\
    :room => ENV['ROOM'], :reconnect => true, :reconnect_wait => 30)

  # This is the single instance of KevbotState that's used liberally in
  # the rest of the program. It's frequently passed as a parameter to
  # methods that might need to manipulate it.      
  state = KevbotState.new (client)

  # Every ~30 seconds, I run some logic to enforce rules against going AFK.
  # Some of this logic involves the RoomQueue   
  client.on :heartbeat do
    room = client.room

    #...snip    

    # Enforce that AFK users lose their positions in the queue.
    queue = state.room_queue
    unless queue.empty? && (room.djs.count < room.dj_capacity)
      head = queue.peek

      #...snip

    end
  end

  #... snip    

  # When users leave the room, I remove them from the queue
  client.on :user_left do |user|
    state.room_queue.remove_user user
    state.last_activity.delete user
    state.sent_dj_reminders.delete user
  end

  client.on :user_booted do |user|
    state.room_queue.remove_user user
  end

  # When a user attempts to start playing music, I make
  # sure that they're at the front of the queue
  client.on :dj_added do |user|
    #...snip    

    room = client.room
    queue = state.room_queue
    if queue.can_user_dj? user
      queue.remove_user user
    else
      user.remove_as_dj
      #...snip
    end

    #...snip
  end

  #...snip
end
```

In addition, there are a couple of chat commands that users can enter that the chatbot will respond to by manipulating the queue. For example, this is the logic for a command to [check the contents of the queue](https://github.com/KevinNorth/Kevbot/blob/9435ccbaa1c725fd7f74fa1d36da2ffd27cd2014/src/commands/check_queue.rb). There are two other commands that also touch the `RoomQueue`.

```
require_relative '../kevbot_state.rb'
require_relative 'command.rb'

class CheckQueueCommand
include Command
  #...snip    

  def execute(parameter, user, client, state)
    room = client.room
    queue = state.room_queue

    if queue.empty?
      room.say "The queue is empty."
      if (user.dj?) && (room.djs.size < room.dj_capacity)
        room.say "Feel free to get on deck!"
      end
    else
      room.say "The queue is: #{queue.check.join(', ')}"
    end
  end

  #...snip    
end
```

I don't like how the behavior that manipulates and enforces the queue is spread out throughout the chatbot. Are there any patterns I can use to consolidate all of this logic in one place? Also, is there a better place for me to put my `RoomQueue` than the `KevbotState`?

[This is a stable commit in the project that uses the design I want feedback on.](https://github.com/KevinNorth/Kevbot/tree/9435ccbaa1c725fd7f74fa1d36da2ffd27cd2014)

Comment: I don't have much time to build an elaborate answer, but here's my two cents : first, much of the data you store in the state should be the responsibility of the room queue ; for instance, deck activity timers, etc. Looking from afar, I'd say your code also misses a User class that would store last activity time, afk time, etc. for ONE user, and be responsible to maintain timers, notify the user, etc. All in all, your code lacks well-defined entities that embody responsibilities. Maybe I'll have a closer look when i have time.

Comment: Quick note: All those `#...snip`s make me think this is off-topic. Could you paste in the full code? (Aside from that, this seems *super* cool! Does it still work?)